# IdentityServer3, Identityserver3.MembershipReboot in asp core

Tags: .net, identityserver3

Can I use `IdentityServer3` and `Identityserver3.MembershipReboot` in `.net core?`

Or is better to use https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

IdentityServer3 is not written in .core and I am not sure if will work correctly with .net core projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Identity Server 4 targets .NET Core. Identity Server 3 targets the .NET Framework.

See https://leastprivilege.com/2016/01/11/announcing-identityserver-for-asp-net-5-and-net-core/ for initial announcement.

Comment: Hi, I know that. But can I use Identity Server 3 in .NET core? I found also this. IdentityServer3 in AspNet5 https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNet5

Comment: No. The token handlers and middleware setup is completely different between the two platforms.

Comment: Thank you. Why then this AspNet5 samples? And why they create this repo (IdentityServer3.Integration.AspNetCore
) https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Integration.AspNetCore?

Comment: .NET Core != ASP.NET Core. That sample is running ASP.NET Core using the .NET Framework. ASP.NET Core can run on both .NET Core and the .NET Framework.

Comment: ok I understand what you want to tell me. So in your opinion this is bad idea and is better to use just IdentityServer4 because you can then deploy it in docker for example

Comment: If you need .NET Core then yes, you'll need to use Identity Server 4 (which is currently in beta/RC). Otherwise if you just need to use docker you could look at using Identity Server 3 running on Mono.

Answer (score 1):

Running IdentityServer3 on ASP.NET Core is not recommended. Either stay with 3 on Katana, or wait for 4 (you can start using 4 today if you are OK with some breaking changes between now and RTM).

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/07/14/net-core-1-0-is-released-but-where-is-identityserver/